# How to create a smooth jumping movement?

Tags: c#, xna

I have this ball that when OnClick needs to jump up 150px and down again. It need to do this in the total of 1 sec (1000ms).

I've tried a couple of methods. One dividing the time in two, first have going up and other half going down... but its somewhat unstable and not that smooth.

Anyone got a idea?

Comment: Physical objects usually fly in a parabolic trajectory. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballistic_curve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want an upside-down parabola that starts at zero and returns to zero at t = 1. The formula is:

```
y = k * t * (1 - t)
```

To figure out *k*, substitute (*t*, *y*) = (0.5, 150) and solve for *k*.